# Connect this NSSting with a String Variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

All I want is to change every time the NSString townLocation.
Because I take data from an API and I don't want to create different API for different location. Also I know that the "+" that I put on the link is not correct and there is not such think in Objective C but I want to make you understand what I want.

```
  NSString*townLocation;    
   NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q="+townLocation+"&units=metric"]];
```

How I must do it ? Im sure you understand that I'm new at Objective C

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to look into the most basic [`NSString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html) documentation to find a method that will do that, `stringWithFormat:`.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=%@&units=metric", townLocation];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

If you're new at Objective-C, a good place to find information like this is to simply search the internet or the iOS Developer Library for the class in question (in this case, `NSString`) to find a myriad of resources at your disposal. Another doc to check would be [Formatting String Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943), which is linked in the `stringWithFormat:` section of the iOS Developer Library, to find more info about formatting strings.